# Check for multiple instances of same object in array

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, duplicates

i am looking for a way to check if an array contains more than 1 instances of the same object. I've been looking around but can't seem to find anything in the javadoc nor stackoverflow.

I am creating a monopoly board game (or in danish, matador) where the fee from landing on one of the fields differs depending on how many of that type of field the player owns.

I have a list in my player class in which i put all the fields that the player buys:

```
   public List<OwnableField> ownsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void buy(OwnableField ownable) {
       pay(ownable.getPrice());
       ownsList.add(ownable);
    }
```

And then i have this method in the specific field class, in which i am working on an if statement to set the fee:

```
public int fee;

public int feeCalc(int diceScore) {

    if(this.getOwner().ownsList.(whatever checks for duplicate object in array)){

        fee = 200 * diceScore;

    } else {

        fee = 100 * diceScore;

    }

    return fee;
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you only want to check for multiple instances of ONE object? - `for (OwnableField o : ownsList) if (o instanceof MyObject) counter++`

Comment: But really, mate. You should just find another another alternative to `rederier`.. they suck. Nobody wants to buy them.

Comment: Yes, it is correct that i only want to check for ONE object, thanks! Also it is a school assignment, so i don't really have a choice. Those fields are actually brewery fields, not rederier - and brewery fields are even worse :)

Comment: Im not sure i understand exactly how it works and how to implement it. The way i understand it, the first: (OwnableField o : ownsList) stores all Objects that extends the class OwnableField and are located in ownsList array into a variable called o? And then you check if any of the objects that you just stored in o, are instances of the object that we are looking for - and then you add 1 to the counter for every object that is an instanceof myObject?

Comment: You're running a loop. You're telling the body of the function `if (o instanceof MyObject) counter++` to be run exactly as many times as there are `OwnableField`'s in the `ownsList` collection. So you don't check if 'any' of the objects stored in `o` is an instance of MyObject; You check if THE object stored in `o` is - several times.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works. I got it to work right after you posted, but nice to actually understand what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proper equals and hash code defined then you can use sets to achive that

```
List list = ...

if(new HashSet(list).size().equals(list.size()){
//same size
} else {
//there was a duplicated element
}
```

If you want to check for one specific object only you could do it with:

```
final Object someObject = ...
List list = ...
int size = FluentIterable.from(list).filter(new Predicate<Object>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Object input) {
            return input == someObject;
        }
    }).size();
if(size > 1) { 
//there is a duplicated element
}
```

Or, if you are looking for an instance of a class, then try:

```
List list = ...
int size = FluentIterable.from(list).filter(Predicates.instanceOf(YourClass.class)).size();
if(size > 1) { 
//there is a duplicated element
}
```